# How to read json file from docx using python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, docx

I have a docx file like below.

```
[ {    "name": "ravi",  
  "city": "chennai",    
  "country": "india"   
}
{

    "name": "raj",  
  "city": "chennai",    
  "country": "india" 
}
]
```

I am trying to read this content as a list of dictionaries. I tried this .

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('2255858_1321163255_worldcupdata.docx')
s=""
for i in document.paragraphs:
    s+=i.text
json_list=s[1:-1].split('}')
```

but I could not convert the string to dict, I am getting value error for the below statement.

```
dict('{    "name": "ravi", "city": "chennai", "country": "india"  }')
```

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `json`

[EDIT]

```
from docx import Document
import regex as re
import json

document = Document('2255858_1321163255_worldcupdata.docx')
s=""
for i in document.paragraphs:
    s+=i.text
p = re.compile('\[(.*?)\]')
d = json.loads(p.search(s).group(0))
```

Do `d = json.loads(your_string)`

d will be your dict

`loads` from json converts string to dict

Comment: i tried that one `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: When you print the extracted string, what do you get? As there must be some problem there, as this should work.

Comment: print (s) gives `' [  {    "name": "ravi", "city": "chennai", "country": "india"  },{..... ' `

Comment: Does it end with a `]` and `}` because that error comes when the input string is not of right format?

Comment: how will you split the data to iterate, if i split by '}' this will be removed from the string

Comment: ends with a  ``  ]``

Comment: Use a regex, have a try, else I'll post the complete answer in some time

Comment: please answer it

Comment: Glad I could help, the `0` in group assumes you have only one match, you can iterate over if needed.